# How to pass an array of string through the rails' form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a trouble with the rails' form, I need to pass to the form of Event an array of emails, I have this attribute members that I want to have like array. I try in this way but it doesn't work, can you help me?

```
<div class="field">
      <%= form.fields_for :members do |p| %>
        <% @group.list_accepted.each do |part| %>
          <%= p.label :email , User.find(part.user_id).username %>
          <%= p.check_box :email, {} ,User.find(part.user_id).email, nil %>
          <br>
        <%end%>
     <% end %>
  </div> 

   params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description,:user_id, :group_id, :start_date, :end_date, members: [:email])
```

the result of this is a set with just the first email {email=> "email@.com"}

Comment: Try adding `[]` to the first parameter of the check_box `p.check_box "email[]"`. Rails interprets this as an array of emails

Comment: it says "Unpermitted parameter"

Comment: You need to permit the Array as well. Change `members: [:email]` to `members: [email: []]`

Comment: it works and i found out that if you introduce {multiple: true} into check box field it return an array with the multiple option. But it return a sring because members into db is a string. Which value can i pass into migration to have return an array?